# Removing and Appending Map Controls on Map Reload

Tags: javascript, overlay, reload

I'm working on a web map that allows the user to choose between two expressions of data by clicking a button. The button reloads the page to connect to a different javascript file successfully. However, each time the page is reloaded, additional sequence and overlay controls are added. I am looking for a way to remove the controls each time the page is reloaded in order to only display one set of controls. 
[image: Map on second re-expression]

Create sequence controls in main.js:

```
  //create range input element (slider)
  $('#panel').append('<input class="range-slider" type="range">');

  // Create skip buttons
  $('#panel').append('<button class="skip" id="reverse">Reverse</button>');
  $('#panel').append('<button class="skip" id="forward">Skip</button>');
```

Reload page in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let changeExpression = function(type) {
        let elem = document.createElement("script");
    if (type === 'heat') {
        elem.src = "js/main_heat.js";
    } else {
        elem.src = "js/main.js";
    }
    map.off();
    map.remove();
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
    }
</script>
```

I've tried "range-slider".remove(), but this deletes the entire map and throws an error saying it is an invalid function. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering with this for a while I was able to find a workaround. Instead of appending sequence controls to the panel, I used L.control.extend to add them to the map container which reloads them each time the page is refreshed.